# powershell function to get CPU and memory usage of multiple server

Tags: powershell

Here's my what my function does

```
{
$input|Foreach-Object{Get-WmiObject -computername $_ win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select SystemName, Average}
}
```

I'm aware that I can't put SystemName on that last pipeline. How do I add another column to the result containing the system name. I also have a separate code for memory usage and I want to combine these two codes(cpu and memory usage).

```
 {   
$input|Foreach-Object{Get-WmiObject -computername $_ -Query "SELECT FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize FROM Win32_OperatingSystem" | Select FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$input|
Foreach-Object {
 Get-WmiObject -computername $_ -Query "SELECT __Server,FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize FROM Win32_OperatingSystem" |
  Select @{l='SystemName';e={$_.__Server}},FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize
}
```

Comment: Close, basically, I want to output computername, cpu and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a script you don't have to do everything in one command. [Best practice #12](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-12)

> The correct way to output information from a PowerShell cmdlet or function is to create an object that contains your data, and then to write that object to the pipeline by using Write-Output.

```
$pcs | % {New-Object -Typename psobject -Property @{'System'=$_;'Average'=((Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $_ -Class win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average).Average);}}
```

Comment: Why are the contents not being passed to -computername? I'm getting an error that saying computer is null or empty

Comment: When I tested on my machine `$pcs = 'Computer1','Computer2'` and I was using PS 3.0

Comment: Ok it works on its own but when I put it in a function form, it doesn't.

Comment: I also tested on PS 2.0 and it worked. I'm not using the `$input` because that is a special variable name.

Comment: `function foo ([string[]] $pcs){ return ($pcs | % {New-Object -Typename psobject -Property @{'System'=$_;'Average'=((Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $_ -Class win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average).Average);}})}` so something like that?

Comment: Here's what I have
`function get-cpumemory
{
$pcs | % {New-Object -Typename psobject -Property @{'System'=$_;'CPU Usage'=((Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $_ -Class win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average).Average);}}
}`

Here's the error:
                                                      
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: I then use get-content server.txt | get-cpumemory. servers.txt contains IP and FQDN.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26682/discussion-between-dumont-and-bobloblaw)

Comment: Your not passing any information to the function, so $pcs is empty. Add a parameter to your function.